# pdflatex bookdown template failing to knit with times new roman

Tags: fonts, pdftex, bookdown

I have a pdflatex bookdown template set up to knit in a times new roman font, but instead is showing as an arial type font. I would like this defined globally preferability (instead of inside each document) I have tried:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Any advice much appreciated!

CSL is below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{glasgowthesis}[]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % comment out for indentation globally 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{b,}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
%\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=-1em}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
% \newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
% \newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
% \newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
% \newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
% \newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
% \newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
% \newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
% \newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
% \newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
% \newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
% \newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
% \newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
% End of CII add

% This gives us rules below the headers
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
     \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \nouppercase \leftmark} % This makes the headers on the RIGHT side pages be italic and use lowercase With Capitals When Specified. I dont think this works.
    \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \nouppercase \rightmark} % This does the same thing to the LEFT side pages
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
  \let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
  \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
    \oldthebibliography{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  }{\endoldthebibliography}

  \let\oldtheindex=\theindex
  \let\endoldtheindex=\endtheindex
  \renewenvironment{theindex}{
    \oldtheindex
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
  }{\endoldtheindex}
}

% Stolen from book.cls and modified
\let\RToldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\if@openright\RTcleardoublepage
            \else\clearpage\fi
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \global\@topnum\z@
            \@afterindentfalse
            \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

% Using this to actually show "Chapter 1" in TOC instead of "1"
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                         {\@chapapp\space\thechapter:\space#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\newcommand{\RTcleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}\newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\let\RToldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\RTcleardoublepage}

%%% Margins
\usepackage[top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=4.0cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 1 inch margin across all sides
% \oddsidemargin 0truemm % add for printing 
 \evensidemargin 15truemm % add for printing 
%%
```

Comment: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` is a macro from the fontspec package. It can only be used with xelatex or lualatex. You cannnot use it with pdflatex.

Comment: From CTAN: "The package [times] is now obsolete, replaced by the mathptmx package". So, load both seems not a good idea.

Comment: They were loaded separately, not together.

Comment: Anyway, forget times. BTW, also forget `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. When is not already loaded by default  (pdflatex) is ignored by  the utf8 based engines (xelatex & lualatex).